# How to redirect stdout/stderr when /dev/null is not writable for normal users

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

How to disable stdout or stderr in bash scripts temporarily?

Of course the most common way is to redirect stdout or stderr to /dev/null.
But on some systems /dev/null may be unwritable for normal users.
I am writing some scripts that is aim to be portable, so I do not prefer using /dev/null

Some blogs/posts say that *>&-* can close stdout, but when I tried *echo 123 >&-* in a bash terminal, it just failed with the message "bash: echo: write error: Bad file descriptor"

Surely I can do it by redirecting stdout or stderr to a tmp file like this:
*some_command > /tmp/null*
But what I want is a more "elegant" way

I think perhaps I can achieve this by using pipe like this:
*some_command | :*

But in this way, it may "pollutes" the exit code of the original command

Comment: I'm curious why `/dev/null` isn't writable by everyone? It normally is.

Comment: yes, I think it would even be a problem if /dev/null is not world writeable. I would think many things might break on the system. Still, the last part of the question is what you need...try 'ls zzzz 2>&1 |:'

Comment: @ChrisJ.Breisch I just edited my question because I just found a big problem of using pipe to achieve this, since it may overwrite the exit code of the original command

Comment: Yes, that will definitely happen. You only get the exit code of the last command in the pipeline, in this case ':'

Comment: If you use `set pipefail` , the exit status isn't clobbered. Also a system with a non usable /dev/null is a broken system.

Comment: Yes, that will work, nos. I was going to add a script example here, but comments aren't flexible enough for that. Or I'm not smart enough to figure it out.

Comment: From the POSIX spec: "The following files shall exist on conforming systems and shall be both readable and writable:

/dev/null
An infinite data source and data sink. Data written to /dev/null shall be discarded. Reads from /dev/null shall always return end-of-file (EOF)." I'd say if `/dev/null` is not writeable, that's an error on the system that needs to be corrected, not worked around.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible way to do what you want:

```
( my_cmd 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3- ) | :
```

This temporarily send `stdout` to a new file handle, `3` and redirect `stderr` to `stdout` so that the `stderr` pipes into the command (in this case, `:`). Then the new file handle is routed back out to `stdout`. These avoid piping the `stdout` of `my_cmd` into `:`. The `-` in closes the handle after it's used.

To check the exist status of `my_cmd` after the above you examine the environment variable `$PIPESTATUS[0]`. `$PIPESTATUS` is a `bash` environment array variable that holds the exit status of each piped command in the last pipe that was done.

I think the really correct answer is to investigate why `/dev/null` isn't world writable. Having it not so is an off-standard system configuration and may cause system problems. The above work-around is a little messy by comparison.

Comment: I just found there is a fatal problem of using pipe, since it may overwrite the exit code of the original command. So are there any ways to do it without pipeline?    <br> (What I want is two things: "disable stdin but keep stdout" and "disable stdout but keep stdin")

Comment: @zcnnbb there's an environment array variable called $PIPESTATUS that holds the exit status of each command in the last foreground pipeline of commands.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I wrote earlier and @nos's comment above, here's an example:

(assuming you have no file called 'zzz' in your current directory, and that '.' is readable)

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o pipefail
ls . 2>&1 |:
echo $?
ls zzz 2>&1 |:
echo $?
```

The pipelines succeed and fail silently and maintain the exit code. Note that you can probably still make a pipeline example where this would not produce the desired results. I haven't come up with one in my head yet, but that doesn't mean it's not out there. The best answer, as many have noted already, is to fix the system so that /dev/null is world writable.

**EDIT**: Changed /bin/sh to /bin/bash, although this probably isn't necessary. But since I haven't tested this against a true Bourne Shell, I decided to err on the side of caution.

**EDIT**: Another script, showing several different redirections, and using the `|&` shortcut for `2>&1 |`. If you run this, you'll notice that some of the `ls` failures return a 141 exit status rather than the expected 2. This is a broken pipe exit status, but still represents a failure.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o pipefail
# start with commands that should succeed
# redirect everything to ':'
echo "ls . |& :"
ls . |& :
echo $?
# redirect only stdout to ':'
echo "ls . | :"
ls . | :
echo $?
# redirect only stderr to ':'
echo "((ls . 1>&3) |& : ) 3>&1"
((ls . 1>&3) |& : ) 3>&1
echo $?
# now move to failures
# redirect everything to ':'
echo "ls zzz |& :"
ls zzz |& :
echo $?
# redirect only stdout to ':'
echo "ls zzz |:"
ls zzz |:
echo $?
# redirect only stderr to ':'
echo "((ls zzz 1>&3) |& : ) 3>&1"
((ls zzz 1>&3) |& : ) 3>&1
echo $?
```

I use two subshells when I'm attempting to destroy stdout but keep stderr. You could do it without the outer one. In fact, that might be better. Instead of getting a broken pipe error, you get a 1 exit status.

Comment: If I recall correctly >| is just an overwrite operation.  It's the same as >, but works even if noclobber is set.